# Make Google Analytics city data showed on the Google map

Tags: google-maps, google, google-fusion-tables

I use the Google fusion table to table to mark city on google map, but there are about 20~25% which quality is ambiguous. How to make the ambiguous data precise?
Here is [my finished map](http://smallcollation.blogspot.com/2013/11/output-google-analytics-geolocation.html) (scroll down to see map)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the quality of your data. 
You can geocode each city with the Google geocoder and see the comparison with your geodata.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false&key=API_KEY
```

Or your can try to geocode with others providers as OSM.